# Geoserver plugin MBTiles,only surpport PNG tile format?

Tags: geoserver

When I use Geoserver plugin MBTiles,I found it only surpport PNG tile format.
It does not surpport some other common format,for example jpeg,tif,webp etc.
I add a layer of these format tile mbtiles then I click "Layer Preview",I get the following error:

[image]

Geoserver run log like this :

[image]

And when I update jdk version,I can not solve this problem.

I am not familiar with Geoserver source code or geotools source code.

[image]

I know I can use other way to publish these formats tile Mbtiles not using Geoserver.

But is it a bug of Geoserver,can they fix it? Or do you encounter this problem also?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your MBTiles either misses some information, or contains misleading information, in particular in the "metadata" table.

According to the [MBTiles specification](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.3/spec.md#content):

> The metadata table is used as a key/value store for settings. It MUST contain these two rows:

> - name (string): The human-readable name of the tileset.
> - format (string): The file format of the tile data: pbf, jpg, png, webp, or an IETF media type for other formats.

In your case, you either don't have the "format" entry (and GeoServer then assumes PNG), or you have one saying "png", but at least some of the tiles turn out not to match that format.

Comment: Yes,your method can solve my problem.Thank you very much.

Comment: If it's working, then please accept the answer :-D